# Why react function reference doesn't change at every render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

React learner here.

I create a new react redux typescript app:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template redux-typescript
```

In the sample code, I add an **useEffect** to dispatch an action only one time the first time the component is rendered:

in src\features\counter\Counter.tsx

```
   const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
   
   ...
 
  useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(increment())
  }, [dispatch]);
```

And I also add another button to change a new state in this component to force a new rendering of the component and be sure that **useEffect** code is called just one time.

The problem is that everything works but I don't understand one thing.

I learn (for sure I'm missing something) that upon each render cycle, "dispatch" function should be redefined. So each render cycle "dispatch" should have a different reference and this should trigger useEffect again.

But this is not was is happening.

Looks like that at each render "dispatch" don't change reference (otherwise useEffect will be called again), but how this is possible? What's the point I'm missing?

I was confused because If I create a custom hook like this:

```
const useRequestHook = () => {
 
  const sendRequest =useCallback(() => {
      console.log("send request invoked")
  }, []);

  return sendRequest;

};

export default useRequestHook;
```

And if I use it in my **Counter** component:

```
      const sendRequest = useRequestHook();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        sendRequest();
      }, [sendRequest]);
```

I have issues when component renders again for example when I click the button. Because the new render will change sendRequest reference and useEffect will be called again, so the solution is to wrap in the useCallback

```
 

     import { useCallback } from "react";
    
    const useRequestHook = () => {
     
      const sendRequest =useCallback(() => {
          console.log("send request invoked")
      }, []);
    
      return sendRequest;
    
    };
    
    export default useRequestHook;
```

Now it worked as expected and as I understand.

Why the behavior is different between "dispatch" and "sendRequest"?

Comment: Can you also share the implementation of the useAppDispatch custom hook?

Comment: If the hook returns a stable value, e.g. a value returned from useMemo or useCallback, then it will be referrentially stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

> This hook returns a reference to the dispatch function from the Redux store.

This is the key. With the custom hook **useAppDispatch** you are actually getting a reference to the dispatch function so you are not recreating the function each time, and that is why useEffect does not get called on each re-render.

Comment: why the function "send request" in "useRequestHook" change reference when "Counter" component render but "dispatch" doesn't?  what's the difference? both are function declared inside a hook.

Comment: It's not about being a hook, especially if it's a custom hook. By using () => {} you are recreating the function each time so you are also getting a new reference. As you found out to make sure that the reference of the function keep being the same you need to memoize it through useCallBack. You didn't share the code of useAppDispatch but I suppose it just calls useDispatch that returns you the same reference function from the redux store, so you are not recreating it as you would with () => {}